# Why does IntelliJ not show the latest version of Grails plugins?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-plugin

I'm on IntelliJ 10 using its out of the box Grails tools (Grails 1.3.7).  I can get a list of Grails plugins from the IDE (the Grails -> Plugins menu item), but it's not as current as the list I get when I execute `grails list-plugin` from OSX Terminal (also Grails 1.3.7).

For example, IntelliJ currently shows the mongodb plugin to be version 1.0-M4 but command line says 1.0-M5.  Grails.org also says 1.0-M5.

How can I get IntelliJ so show me the same list of Grails plugins that Grails.org has?

*PS:* Yes, I know I can still install plugins from the command line.

*PPS:* I have tried refreshing the list of Grails plugins from the IDE (the Grails -> Plugins menu item, then click reload).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this issue. On my machine IDEA shows "1.0-M5". IDEA gets list of plugin and its versions from %USER_HOME%/.grails/1.3.7/plugins-list-grailsCentral.xml. Grails uses the same file.
Could you look which version is set in this file? (find string '<plugin name="mongodb"')

Comment: Thanks for helping.  It's 1.0-M5:  <plugin name="mongodb" latest-release="1.0-M5">

Comment: Strange... May be IDEA looks to other file. Do you have any other Grails installations?

Comment: Not that I can tell.  My ~/.grails folder only has the one subdirectory, "1.3.7".  And a search of my system only turns up that single .grails folder.